# How integrate swiftui button in an expo module

Tags: swift, react-native, swiftui, expo

I'm trying to implement the FamilyActivityPicker in Swift through expo modules in my react native application. I need this functionality so that the user can choose an app that can be restricted through monitoring.

This is the example code from apples documentation that i would like to implement
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/familycontrols/familyactivitypicker

```
struct FamilyActivityPickerView: View {
  @State var selection = FamilyActivitySelection()
  @State var isPresented = false

   var body: some View {
       Button("Present FamilyActivityPicker") { isPresented = true }
       .familyActivityPicker(isPresented: $isPresented,
                             selection: $selection)
       .onChange(of: selection) { newSelection in
           let applications = selection.applications
           let categories = selection.categories
           let webDomains = selection.webDomains
       }
   }
}
```

This is my expo module

```
import ExpoModulesCore
import DeviceActivity
import FamilyControls
import SwiftUI

public class ScreentimeModule: Module {
  // Each module class must implement the definition function. The definition consists of components
  // that describes the module's functionality and behavior.
  // See https://docs.expo.dev/modules/module-api for more details about available components.
  public let center = DeviceActivityCenter()
  
  public func definition() -> ModuleDefinition {
    
    // Sets the name of the module that JavaScript code will use to refer to the module. Takes a string as an argument.
    // Can be inferred from module's class name, but it's recommended to set it explicitly for clarity.
    // The module will be accessible from `requireNativeModule('Screentime')` in JavaScript.
    Name("Screentime")

    // Sets constant properties on the module. Can take a dictionary or a closure that returns a dictionary.
    Constants([
      "PI": Double.pi
    ])

    // Defines event names that the module can send to JavaScript.
    Events("onChange")

    AsyncFunction("authFamilyControls") {
      let center = AuthorizationCenter.shared
      do {
        try await center.requestAuthorization(for: .individual)
      } catch {
        print("error")
      }
    }    

    Function("startMonitor") {
      let schedule = DeviceActivitySchedule(
        intervalStart: DateComponents(hour: 0, minute:0), 
        intervalEnd: DateComponents(hour:23,minute:59), 
        repeats: true
        )
      
      try center.startMonitoring(.daily, during: schedule)
    }

    // Defines a JavaScript function that always returns a Promise and whose native code
    // is by default dispatched on the different thread than the JavaScript runtime runs on.
    AsyncFunction("setValueAsync") { (value: String) in
      // Send an event to JavaScript.
      self.sendEvent("onChange", [
        "value": value
      ])
    }
    

    // Enables the module to be used as a native view. Definition components that are accepted as part of the
    // view definition: Prop, Events.
    View(ScreentimeView.self) {
      // Defines a setter for the `name` prop.
      Prop("name") { (view: ScreentimeView, prop: String) in
        print(prop)
      }
    }
  }
}

extension DeviceActivityName {
  static let daily = Self("daily")
}
```

I've tried wrapping it in a function but since it is a view, it expectedly did not work. But I have used the requestAuthorization in another function which seemed to work (it is also a form of view). I'm unsure how it would be implemented with the View() part of the module.

Comment: Please [edit] and add a link to "example code from apples documentation"

Comment: Added a bounty because I'm genuinely curious on how this gets implemented - godspeed on a "swift" response :)

Comment: @Michael, I'm curious why it should be implemented by the native side? I can't understand this need.

Comment: tbh, we had to ditch expo. the moment any customization came along it became a burden. It was awesome to get started with but we found expo and oob reactNative can only get us 80% of the way to a feature complete app. be interested to saee if your code works in the bare bones workflow

Comment: Thanks @AmerllicA and @danielRicado .  AFAIK `familyActivityPicker` needs a binding and I'd have no idea how to do this non-natively. I've been able to get the Expo bridge working where it's taking the SwiftUI `View` and being attached to the `ExpoView` (which ultimately extends UIKit's `UIView`) as a subView via UIHostingController per https://docs.expo.dev/modules/module-api/#view, but the content isn't rendering as expected. It theoretically should work if the frame or bounds are set up correctly.

Comment: The managed workflow is honestly fine as-is and can prebuild --clean, but agree I am modifying the code directly to confirm it works, then adjusting it via modules so we stay within managed workflow. I definitely appreciate your note about looking outside of expo as well.

Comment: I think for the bounty at least, it would be enough to have a working example of a  content like a `Button` rendering from a SwiftUI `View` into ExpoView (extended UIKit `UIView`) and called from a Sample.tsx (ReactNative)

Answer (score 0):

For any future onlookers, it is fully possible to use the familyActivityPicker (both inline via `FamilyActivityPicker(..)` which is a `View` and via a binding to a button i.e. `Button{..}.familyActivityPicker(..)`. You need to use UIHostingController to convert SwiftUI's View to UIKit's UIView via `UIController(rootView: yourSwiftUIView()).view` as Expo recommends. Where I got stuck was not understanding Screens, Stacks, and iOS's design model fundamentals, which is not Expo's fault; you need to understand constraints, anchors and how your `frame` gets determined, and set dimensions as needed. I highly recommend taking a few tutorials on SwiftUI development without Expo, as it really helped me.